# How to loop through WPF StackPanel static Items?

Tags: wpf, element, stackpanel, loops

Probably very easy but I am having trouble to figure this out (also Google doesn't seem to help much).

How can I loop through the statically declared elements (no databinding - elements are declared in the xaml) of a StackPanel?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean the `StackPanel`'s children?

```
foreach (var child in stackPanel.Children)
{
    //do something with child
}
```

A more generic solution that would work regardless of the parent would be to use `LogicalTreeHelper` or `VisualTreeHelper`, depending on what WPF tree you wish to traverse:

```
foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(stackPanel))
{
    //do something with child
}
```

Comment: thanks - just found it myself but your answer is spot-on. 
couldn't find it as I was looking for "Items"!

Comment: While Kent is 100% correct, if you're editing XAML objects directly in your code-behind, it's most likely the case that you're not using databinding where you should be. Not always the case though :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought just the same as Johnldol, since in my case I had one child and I knew its type; I didn't want to obscure my code by an unnecessary loop. So this is how I reached the TextBlock inside the Hyperlink:

```
        var looper = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(objHyperlink).GetEnumerator();
        looper.MoveNext();
        TextBlock objTextBlock = (looper.Current as InlineUIContainer).Child as TextBlock;
```