# How can i bind a border visibility to the visibility of containing children objects

Tags: wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I have this kind of code below, how can I bind the visibility of the Border to the visibility of all the labels?

Of course the number of rows and labels is not fixed.

```
<Border BorderBrush=Black
        BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <Label DataContext="{Binding MyObject[1]}"
                Content="{Binding MyText}"
                Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}"/>

         <Label DataContext="{Binding MyObject[2]}"
                Content="{Binding MyText}"
                Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}"/>
[...]
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean that if one of the labels is visible, you wish the border to be visible?

Comment: yes, or if all labels are not visible then i want my border to be collapsed, avoiding to show an empty border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are changing the amount of rows and labels.

I assume that `MyObject` is a `List<MyObject>`. In that case what you can do is simply bind the list to the `Visibility` property with a `Converter` that loops through the objects checking if they are all invisible.

### XAML:

#### Namespace:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyConverters"
```

#### Window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:ObjectBorderVisibilityConverter 
               x:Key="MyObjectBorderVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>


<Border BorderBrush=Black
    BorderThickness="{Binding MyObject, Converter={StaticResource MyObjectBorderVisibilityConverter}">
[...]
```

### Converters Code:

```
namespace MyConverters
{
    public class ObjectBorderVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Visibility v = Visibility.Hidden;

            List<MyObject> myObjects = value as List<MyObject>;
            foreach(Object myobject in myObjects)
            {
                   if (myobject.IsVisible)
                       v = Visibility.Visible;
            }      
            return v;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ObjectBorderVisibilityConvertercan only be used OneWay.");        
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you are going to have to explain how you got the amount of rows and labels to be dynamic and we can work from there.

Hope this helps

u_u

---

## EDIT

Well according to your comment you have a list of strings which contain the name of the object you want to display in each `ListViewItem`. I'm not going to ask why you are doing it this way, I assume you have a reason. I just wanna say have you tried Key Value pairs?

What I would do here is pass the grid itself as a parameter in the converter, and loop through its children using a [LogicalTreeHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420763/how-to-loop-through-wpf-stackpanel-static-items) inside the converter.

### Revised Border:

```
<Window.Resources>
<converters:ObjectBorderVisibilityConverter 
           x:Key="MyObjectBorderVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>


<Border BorderBrush=Black
        BorderThickness="{Binding MyObject, Converter={StaticResource MyObjectBorderVisibilityConverter}", ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=myGrid, BindsDirectlyToSource=True>
       <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
       [...]
```

### Revised Converter

```
namespace MyConverters
{
    public class ObjectBorderVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Visibility v = Visibility.Hidden;
            Grid myGrid = parameter as Grid;
            List<MyObject> myObjects = value as List<MyObject>;
            foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(myGrid))
            {
                   if(child.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Label)
                      if (((Label)child).Visibility = Visibility.Visible)
                           v = Visibility.Visible;
            }     
            return v;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ObjectBorderVisibilityConvertercan only be used OneWay.");        
        }
    }
}
```

I coded this all by hand so there's prolly a bunch of errors, but I hope you get the point.

u_u

Comment: In fact the rows are generated by code from a list of string and generate the bindings according to the strings. And it does one binding with the ".IsVisible" property of the object named by the string. So i may know the possible visible items number but not the real numbers as i do not have in my class wich construct the row the real object but only names to create bindings.

Comment: @user1300261 I updated my answer, hope it helps. Keep me posted